# Python XlsxWriter: Creates too Many Conditional Formatting Rules in Excel

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I believe I have written this correctly and it appears correct when viewed however, when viewing the conditional formatting rules in Excel it shows that there are multiple of the same rule.
This causes issues with large data sets and it dramatically slows down the function of excel.

[View of excel rules manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyhMI.png)

```
# BM - Set Conditional Formatting #

               format8 = workbook.add_format({'font_color':'#FF0000'})


               format9 = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#00B050'})



               sheet1.conditional_format('B15:B200', {'type': 'cell',
                                                       'criteria': 'between',
                                                       'minimum':  3.0000001,
                                                       'maximum':  9999,
                                                       'format': format8})

               sheet1.conditional_format('B15:B200', {'type': 'cell',
                                                       'criteria': 'between',
                                                       'minimum': 0,
                                                       'maximum': 3,
                                                       'format': format9})


               sheet1.conditional_format('C15:C200', {'type': 'cell',
                                                       'criteria': 'between',
                                                       'minimum':  33,
                                                       'maximum':  9999,
                                                       'format': format8})

               sheet1.conditional_format('C15:C200', {'type': 'cell',
                                                       'criteria': 'between',
                                                       'minimum': 0,
                                                       'maximum': 32.9999,
                                                       'format': format9})



               sheet1.conditional_format('D15:D200', {'type': 'cell',
                                                       'criteria': '=',
                                                       'value': '"Fail"',
                                                       'format': format8})

               sheet1.conditional_format('D15:D200', {'type': 'cell',
                                                       'criteria': '=',
                                                       'value': '"Pass"',
                                                       'format': format9})
```

Comment: The only way an XlsxWriter file could have multiple versions of the same rule is if multiple versions of the same rule are added by the calling application. Are the rules being added in a loop or multiple function calls or something similar?